# How to include sitemap.xml from Wordpress in TYPO3

Tags: wordpress, typo3, sitemap

I have an installation of TYPO3 and an installation of Wordpress and want to have a sitemap.xml for search engines which includes sites from both systems.

Currently the sitemap of the TYPO3 installation is generated with typoscript (I basically use [this generator](http://www.oliver-thiele.de/cms-typo3/tutorials/google-sitemap-mit-typoscript.html)). In Wordpress there is no extension installed to generate a sitemap yet.

Edit: TYPO3 is installed in domain.tld/ and Wordpress is in a subdirectory domain.tld/blog.

I am open to use any way to merge sites from both systems in one sitemap. That could either be extensions for one or both CMS or a script running separately. Or maybe there is a way to parse the sitemap.xml from Wordpress in typoscript.

Does anyone know a way to merge the sitemaps?

Comment: Obviously there is no way to achieve directly what I asked for. Thanks Merec for that piece of information. Luckily I found a solution that caters my needs: A sitemap index where one can link multiple sitemaps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not direct way to handle this. Typoscript can not parse external files. The only way to get a merge is creating a new simple extension which gives you the output of both sitemaps merges.